# How to add logging to try/catch with the borrowing pattern

Tags: scala

How can I add logging in the case of an exception in the code below?

I tried to add a catch, **but then I get an error saying that Unit does not conform to the type T**.

Is there a trick around this somehow?

```
private def withClient[T](body: Jedis => T): T = {
  var jedis: Jedis = null
  try {
    jedis = pool.getResource
    body(jedis)
  }
  catch {
    case _ => println("hllo")
  }
  finally {
    if(jedis != null) jedis.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to log the result of applying `jedis` to `body`? How about `val result = body(jedis); log.info(result); result` Note that the last statement inside the try block should be `result` which is of type T.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the case of an exception you are returning the value of `println("hllo")` which is `Unit`

You need to change the return type to something that represents the fact that you may not have a value, I'd suggest `Try[T]` or if you don't care to carry the exception data out of the function you could use `Option[T]`

```
private def withClient[T](body: Jedis => T): Try[T] = {
  var jedis: Jedis = null
  Try(
    try {
      jedis = pool.getResource
      body(jedis)
    }
    catch {
      case e => 
        println("hllo")
        throw e
    }
    finally {
      if(jedis != null) jedis.close()
    }
  )
}
```

or

```
private def withClient[T](body: Jedis => T): Option[T] = {
  var jedis: Jedis = null
    try {
      jedis = pool.getResource
      Some(body(jedis))
    }
    catch {
      case e => 
        println("hllo")
        None
    }
    finally {
      if(jedis != null) jedis.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `body` function throws an exception instead of returning a `T`,
there's pretty much nothing you can do--you have to propagate the
exception forward instead of returning a `T` from `withClient`. `Try` is
the right approach to handle this because it safely captures the
exception and allows you to do something only if there was an exception
thrown. E.g.,

```
private def withClient[T](body: Jedis => T): T = {
  val jedis = pool.getResource
  val tryT = scala.util.Try(body(jedis))

  jedis.close()
  tryT.failed foreach { e => println(e.getMessage) }
  tryT.get
}
```

The following points are notable:

- We got rid of `null` and `var`
- We don't need to worry about `pool.getResource` throwing an exception
  because if it does, we can't go ahead anyway and we don't have to
  worry about closing the resource because the exception means it was
  never opened in the first place.
- We make sure we close the `jedis` resource regardless of exception
  because if there was an exception, it would've been safely caught in
  the `Try`
- We print a message only if there is any exception
- We 'force' a value using `Try#get` only if there was no exception, and
  if there was an exception, it will get rethrown here.

Comment: "We don't need to worry about pool.getResource" The exception could be after you get the resource potentially, I don't agree..

Comment: @Blankman `pool.getResource` will either throw an exception _or_ secure and return the resource. It can't do both. In either case we are good.